# Obj-C: Check if object exists in NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to check if NSString 'testing' (47) exists inside of my NSMutableArray 'self.checkfriendData'. I'm using the code below, though after logging my if statement it appears as though it's never executed (even though the statement is true - see console data below, uid = 47, and thus hiding my object should fire?) Any idea as to why this isn't working? Help is much appreciated!

**ViewController.m**

```
   NSMutableDictionary *viewParams3 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParams3 setValue:@"accepted_friends" forKey:@"view_name"];
    [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams3 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        self.checkfriendData = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;

        NSString *testing = @"47";


        NSArray *friendorNo = self.checkfriendData;

        if ([friendorNo containsObject:testing]) // YES
        {

            self.addFriend.hidden = YES;
        }


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    }];
```

**Here's what's inside self.checkfriendData:**

```
 2017-05-18 19:36:07.266529-0700 This is the friend data check (
            {
            body = "My name is Britt";
            friendphoto = "/sites/default/files/stored/x.jpg";
            "node_title" = "Britt";
            uid = 47;
        }
    )
```

Comment: What is the type of the object associated with key `uid`? Also should `friendorNo` be of type `NSDictionary`?

Comment: @CRD uid would be NSDictionary (it would appear) - that said, if I simply change NSString testing to NSDictionary *testing, would this solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `NSArray` contains `NSDictionary`s and you are asking if the array contains an `NSString`.  The answer will always be no as the array doesn't directly contain any `NSString`s.

If you want to search for the `uid` of `47` you will have to iterate over the array and check the `uid` key of each `NSDictionary` for the value `47`.

The code for this would look something like:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in friendorNo) {
    if ([dict[@"uid"] isEqualToString:testing]) {
        self.addFriend.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how this code would look? I've tried checking the specific dictionary uid for 47 before, and it still doesn't seem to execute? E.g. if self.checkfriendData objectForKey:@"uid" contains 47...

Comment: Lol made some minor edits, all good. That said, should I define uid as an NSDictionary in my .h file then? It's not currently defined (I thought objectForKey states the dictionary to look for inside the data being returned?)

Comment: `uid` is an `NSString` inside an `NSDictionary` that is inside an `NSArray`.  You can't simply ask the `NSArray` if it contains an `NSString` with value `47` because the `NSArray` knows nothing about the structure of the `NSDictionary`s that it contains.

Comment: Thanks a million! :)